# Combine models into a model

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

How can I simplify the wire structure? I can't simplify it after joining with Join and Booleans is not working well (with Union option).

Thanks in advanced!

Marcell

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like *Boolean* doesn't work well because of overlapping faces. Maybe there's another to do it, but to merge 2 crossed Parallelepipeds, you could use the *Tinycad* addon:

- Download the *Tinycad* addon: https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/mesh_tinyCAD
- Enable it in your Preferences.
- Select your whole mesh and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Tinycad* > *XALL/Intersect Selected Edges*.
- It has created some additional vertices on the crossing edges but it has also deleted faces.
- Remove all the doubles with <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*.
- Fill the faces with <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Very super! But it takes a little time to do it. Thank you!

Comment: maybe you could have avoided it at the beginning of your process, but as we don't know what it was... (and maybe someone will give a simplest solution)